# Thymeleaf integration with Typescript

Tags: typescript, thymeleaf

I am looking to integrate Thymleaf within my Typescript experiments.
So far i haven't found a combination on how to best integrate my thymleaf variables with typescript and am wondering if anyone in community has figured this out?

At this stage i am storing thymeleaf variables in hidden fields, whose values are then being pulled out by typescript and used for further processing.

Comment: well.. thymeleaf generates html code on the server, you can't really integrate it with typescript other than maybe generating script tags with variable definitions for the browser to run when the page is loaded.

Comment: if you need information from the server in the client you should consider making some rest services and using ajax to call them. :)

Comment: @toskv yea that's what i've done as well. Got a restfully call to pull data that is required for further processing so there is no actual storage of it on page without use. Was just curious to know whether there is a capability for thymeleaf to work hand in hand with typescript.

Comment: All it does is to generate html. So you are limited to what you could encode in a static page. :) also typescript ends up as plain javascript in the browser, dont expect it to do more than javzscript in that regard. :)

Comment: @toskv yea i know. Got a workaround that does the trick.